# Pathing around a centerposition, how can I skip the line from center?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm creating a custom shape, a hexagon to be exact. I've draw them around a centerpoint as following:

```
PathSegmentCollection segmentCollection = new PathSegmentCollection();
segmentCollection.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(x + tileXDelta / 2, y + tileRadius / 2) });     // 1
segmentCollection.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(x + tileXDelta / 2, y-tileRadius / 2) });       // 2
segmentCollection.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(x + 0, y-tileRadius) });                        // 3
segmentCollection.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(x-tileXDelta / 2, y-tileRadius / 2) });         // 4
segmentCollection.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(x - tileXDelta / 2, y + tileRadius / 2) });     // 5
segmentCollection.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(x + 0, y + tileRadius) });                      // 6
segmentCollection.Add(new LineSegment() { Point = new Point(x + tileXDelta / 2, y + tileRadius / 2) });     // 7
```

and the result is:

[image]

The problem here is that it draws a line from its centerposition to the first corner. Is there a way I can skip that line?

Comment: Your collection of points is likely not causing the problem.  You have correctly navigated around the perimeter.  It is likely that the issue is elsewhere in your code.  If the issue were with your segment collection we would see a "0,0" in your segment collection, but we don't.  My guess would be that whatever is drawing using these segments, is starting from a point not in your segment list, aka the point 0,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you're snippet doesn't show it, you should be placing this PathSegmentCollection inside of a PathFigure which has a StartPoint property. You likely need to set this to

```
new Point(x + tileXDelta / 2, y + tileRadius / 2)
```

Also, once you've defined the StartPoint, you only need the last six points in your PathSegmentCollection, as the StartPoint takes on the role of the first point.